# How can I use SQL pivot command to convert a single column of rows to a single row of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have seen a lot of similar questions but not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to convert a single column of

I'm using

```
SELECT Column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Table_name = 'LibraryInventory'
```

to get the column names of my table. However, they're being returned in a single row such as this

```
ID
-----|
NAME 
-----|
TITLE
-----|
```

I need a way to have these put into a long single row of columns so I can use it in Java how I'm planning like: |ID| NAME| TITLE|

Does anyone know a simple way to do this? I've seen people use pivot however they have much more complicated tables so struggled to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a prepared statement:

```
SELECT @query :=  
  group_concat(concat('''', Column_name, ''''))
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Table_name = 'LibraryInventory' ;

set @query = concat(' SELECT ', @query, ''';');

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean separate them with a line, I was just using those to separate the columns. I need them to be each in a separate column.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I basically mean I'd want the results to all be in the same row but different columns. So instead of the results of my query above, going down, all in the same column but different rows, they'd be going across. So ID in column 1, Name in column 2, Title in column 3 if you see what I mean, but all in row 1.

Comment: @kierabennett check my edited answer.